# Get a specific attribute from a class name with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get only the values of specific attributes ("Followers", "Followings", "Likes") with Selenium.

[image: inspector]

I have tried the following

```
following = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='number']").get_attribute("Following")
followers = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='number']").get_attribute("Followers")
likes = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='number']").get_attribute("Likes")
```

but it does not return anything after printing it.

In my case, I want only the values: 0 , 98, 73

Comment: if it is in `<frame>` then you may need `.switch_to`

Comment: you can  try to use `find_elements` (with char `s` in word `elements`) to get all of then as list - ie. `all_numbers = find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='number']")` and later use `following = all_numbers[0]. ...`, `followers = all_numbers[1]. ...`, `likes = all_numbers[2]. ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 elements having the same class, you have to differentiate them or create different xpaths to point to the specific elements.
You want to take the text of that element or the innerText attribute:

```
#version 1 using text
following = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//strong[@title='Following']").text
followers = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//strong[@title='Followers']").text
likes = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//strong[@title='Likes']").text

print (following, followers,likes)

#version 2 using attribute innerText
following_attribute_innerText = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//strong[@title='Following']").get_attribute("innerText")
followers_attribute_innerText = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//strong[@title='Followers']").get_attribute("innerText")
likes_attribute_innerText = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//strong[@title='Likes']").get_attribute("innerText")

print (following_attribute_innerText, followers_attribute_innerText,likes_attribute_innerText)

#other way to get the xpath using the parent class
following_other_xpath = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='number']/strong[@title='Following']").text
followers_other_xpath = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='number']/strong[@title='Followers']").text
likes_other_xpath = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='number']/strong[@title='Likes']").text

print (following_other_xpath, followers_other_xpath,likes_other_xpath)
```